# Why won't Ubuntu Terminal accept "\" character?

Tags: command-line

I can't get my terminal shell to accept a <kbd>\</kbd> when I type it in.  Nothing happens.  I've Googled but haven't seen anything which seems to address this.  I have no idea where I would start to trouble shoot.

EDIT:

I can use the \ in eclipse, any text editor (including nano or other command line tools).  The exact command in question is:

```
find -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

If I copy and paste that line in, the `\` character disappears.  If I then try and type it in, nothing happens.

The only place this is a problem is int he actual shell command line.

Thanks.

EDIT TWO:

Seems to be some confusion.  If I copy the above command onto my command line, WITHOUT PRESSING ENTER (I.E not executing) This is what is in my shell:

```
$find -type f -exec chmod -x {} ;
```

If I then try and enter a `\` to escape the `;` the symbol Does not Appear.  If I press enter at any time while this command has been entered in the above circumstances it FAILS to execute, due to the ; not being passed into the command.

Edit 3:

I'm using GNOME 3.4.1.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: What about any text editor? Does it work fine..?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What exactly do you mean by you "can't get the terminal to accept \"? What do you mean by "nothing happens"? What exactly is the command you are trying to do?

Comment: Are you saying that when you hit the \ key it does not enter the character?  or something else?  Do other windows accept the keypress and show the \ key?  Do other programs?

Comment: Thans, see edits.

Comment: Now! That makes some sense.. :)

Comment: Does the \ key work again if you invoke a subshell as `bash --noediting`? If so it may be that you have accidentally bound the key to some macro action (the `--noediting` disables readline). If that's the case, check for anything unusual in `/etc/inputrc` or your `~/.inputrc` file if you have one. You could also try (from the `--noediting` subshell) `bind -P | grep '\\\\'` to see if it lists anything for a literal (i.e. escaped) backslash.

Comment: @Steeldriver, bash --noediting gives me the slash back.  Going to try your other suggestions.  Put it as an answer, assuming I figure it out from there i'll accept this.

Comment: What would 'unusual' be?  everything in the inputrc looks fine to me (a lot of \eOH and such, but all normal system binds)

Comment: Ok, looks like someone had bound a somethign incorectly (I share the machine).  Slash is back in a normal shell!  Thanks!  If you put this as an answer I will accept!

Comment: @user2757729 so, how did you solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that the backslash key has become bound to some readline command (`readline` is the library that allows in-situ editing of shell commands, for example binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to the `backward-delete-char` action).

To test if that might be the case, you can try starting a bash subshell with readline editing disabled

```
bash --noediting
```

If the backslash key works in that subshell, then the places to look for the rogue keybinding definition would be `/etc/inputrc` for the global configuration and `~/.inputrc` for per-user configuration. You could also try printing out and searching the currently defined keybindings from the command line using

```
bind -P | grep '\\\\'
```

The extra backslashes are required because a literal backslash will appear in the readline configuration as `\\`, each of which needs a further escape in the shell. Obviously you can only do that in the subshell, if the backslash is being bound in the regular shell.

FYI there is a `bind` command option to remove a binding, but it is not clear how to input the `keyseq` argument when it is already bound

```
-r  keyseq         Remove the binding for KEYSEQ.
```

For further information see `help bind` in the bash command line

Answer (score 1):

`\` escapes whatever character follows it. `;` explicitly ends a command. `\;` means escape the `;` and pass it to the command you are invoking inside find (everything after `-exec`. With \ the semicolon applies to `chmod` whereas without \ the semicolon would apply to `find`.

Your terminal does recognize `\`. When you type it in your terminal, you tell your terminal to escape the next character - which you do not provide.

If you want to display \ as a character, escape it. Type `\\`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you're understanding.  It's not that I can enter the command, and everything works.  The escape character never makes it into the terminal.  See second round of edits.

Comment: Oh sorry. Are you using Gnome Terminal?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 12.04, default stuff.   I think that's Gnome?  How would I check.

Comment: In the menu click Help -> About.

Comment: Added that detail to quesiton as edit 3.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if that's the root cause in your case but I can reproduce a similar behavior by entering this command:

```
stty eof \\
```

It can be corrected with:

```
stty sane
```

You might want to try the latter command to see if that fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a "macBook Air" 2015, with "Parallels 11", and a virtual machine "Ubuntu". My keyboard is the "reduced" Apple wireless. I have chosen, "French Macintosh" (because I'm french...!) for the keybord in the MENU, but in the Terminal of Ubuntu,initially,I couldn't make a "\" nor a "|". 
So I go to the "Paramètres Système", "Saisie de texte" ("text typing"?) and click on the button "Paramètres du clavier" (Keyboard Parameters) in the right down corner of the window. In the second new window, I select "Saisie" ("Typing"?) and then the line "Touche de caractères alternatifs" ("alternate chars Key" ?); now clicking on the right end of that line, it is possible to make a choice between many special Keys... In my case, NO key was initially defined, and I've selected "Alt Left" to emulate the normal action under Mac OS X. 
Long to explain, but quick and easy to do!
Guy de Pernon